# Why does Unity RegisterType<TFrom, TTo> not re-register mappings correctly

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I need to register many Type mappings but for just a few I need to re-register using different dependecy injected Properties.

With Unity this appears impossible and it seems to be a bug with `RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>()`

Here is a unit test to demonstrate that the 2nd call does not clear the previous Dependency graph

```
[TestClass]
public class UnityContainerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UnityShouldCorrectlyResolveReRegisteredType()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IB, B>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
                 .RegisterType<IA, A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionProperty("B", new B()))

            //now re-register mapping without property override, this should 
            //mean that A.B is resolved to our previously registered singleton but it doesnt
            //comment out the line above and notice the test passes

                 .RegisterType<IA, A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        var a = container.Resolve<IA>();
        var b = container.Resolve<IB>();

        Assert.AreEqual(a.B, b);
    }
}

public class A : IA
{
    [Dependency] public IB B { get; set; }
}

public interface IA
{
    IB B { get; set; }
}

public class B : IB { }

public interface IB { }
```

Anyone know of any workarounds?

**Update** I have raised an 'issue' on the Unity Codeplex project portal, if you have experienced this issue then I suggest you upvote my request to have it fixed https://unity.codeplex.com/workitem/12777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when `A` is registered with an `InjectionProperty` a policy gets created inside Unity to resolve the `B` Dependency.  The policy is associated with the build key for type `A` and is of type `SpecifiedPropertiesSelectorPolicy` (which implements `IPropertySelectorPolicy`).  This policy stores the InjectionProperty value (i.e. `new B()`).

When `A` is re-registered again that policy is not removed from the policy list so when `IA` (and eventually `A`) is resolved Unity finds the `IPropertySelectorPolicy` associated with the build key for type `A` and uses the value to inject into `A`.

One solution is to remove the `IPropertySelectorPolicy`.  Once removed, when `A` is resolved Unity will create a new Policy to resolve the `B` dependency and this will return the existing singleton registered with the container.

With this in place the unit test should pass:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnityShouldCorrectlyResolveReRegisteredType()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<IB, B>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
             .RegisterType<IA, A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), 
                                  new InjectionProperty("B", new B()))


    container.RegisterType<IA, A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
                                  new ClearPropertySelectorPolicy());

    var a = container.Resolve<IA>();
    var b = container.Resolve<IB>();

    Assert.AreEqual(a.B, b);
}

public class ClearPropertySelectorPolicy : InjectionMember
{
    public override void AddPolicies(Type serviceType,
        Type implementationType,
        string name,
        Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IPolicyList policies)
    {
        policies.Clear<IPropertySelectorPolicy>(
            new NamedTypeBuildKey(implementationType, name));
    }
}
```

But what if a property wasn't being injected (maybe a dependency in the constructor)?  In that case clearing the IPropertySelectorPolicy wouldn't work;  we would need to clear another policy (but what policy to clear?).  I think the following clears all policies for a build key:

```
public class ClearAllPolicies : InjectionMember
{
    public override void AddPolicies(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, string name, IPolicyList policies)
    {
        var buildKey = new NamedTypeBuildKey(implementationType, name);

        policies.Clear<IBuildKeyMappingPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IConstructorSelectorPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IBuildPlanCreatorPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IBuildPlanPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IMethodSelectorPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IPropertySelectorPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<ILifetimeFactoryPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<ILifetimePolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IBuilderPolicy>(buildKey);

        DependencyResolverTrackerPolicy.RemoveResolvers(policies, buildKey);
    }
}
```

Some caveats:

- policies.Clear() is fairly expensive due to locking
- this is based on a few minutes analysis and has not been tested (besides your unit test) -- the scenarios can get quite complicated.
- concurrent registrations and resolves can cause issues so if that is the scenario you might have to manage synchronization on your own.

Also, I wouldn't really recommend this approach as a general purpose (non-testing) approach.  There may be other approaches that could work (e.g. named registrations, resolver overrides, factories, etc.) depending on the scenario.  Unity tends to work best if you "set it and forget it". That is, at application start up all registrations are performed and then for the duration of the application objects are resolved without modifying registrations.

Comment: Yea this does look to be problematic. My approach is certainly fire and forget, this is all at startup. I have a method that registers every type of a certain bastype. Then for 1 viewmodel I would like to redirect it to use a different set of properties. It feels like a pretty standard use case and something that unity really should support, slow or otherwise. The current implementation is plain confusing.

Comment: OK, I understand your scenario more now.  Another approach would be to exclude that type during the base type registration and then register the different properties after.  That way there is only one registration for that type.

Comment: Yea, its a bit of a pain but I am already looking at that approach. thanks for the analysis

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the source code of Unity and it seems that the existing BuildPlan of a type gets only removed, when the InjectionMembers array passed to RegisterType has a length greater than 0.

```
if (injectionMembers.Length > 0)
{
    this.ClearExistingBuildPlan(to, name);
    foreach (InjectionMember injectionMember in injectionMembers)
      injectionMember.AddPolicies(from, to, name, (IPolicyList) this.policies);
}
```

A possible workaround for your described problem is to use an InjectionFactory as an InjectionMember for your second RegisterType call.

```
.RegisterType<IA, A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c=>c.Resolve<IB>());
```

Comment: Hmmm.. ok I suspected something like that.. thanks for looking into it and the suggestion, it is not ideal in my situation, but may have to do

Comment: The InjectionFactory will work but the injectionMembers.Length > 0 is a bit of a red herring since even if an InjectionMember is supplied the dependency will not be cleared.